# In Jest, is it possible to mock a module in a nested callback, so you can mock it more than once using different properties?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

This works:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { isAndroid } from '../../helpers/platform';

jest.mock('react-native', () => ({
  Platform: {
    OS: 'android'
  }
}));

describe('isAndroid', () => {
  test('validates truthy', () => {
    expect(isAndroid).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

This does not:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { isAndroid } from '../../helpers/platform';

describe('isAndroid', () => {

  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.mock('react-native', () => ({
      Platform: {
        OS: 'android'
      }
    }));
  });

  test('validates truthy', () => {
    expect(isAndroid).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: I would expect `beforeAll(() => { jest.setMock('react-native', {
      Platform: {
        OS: 'android'
      }
    ); });` and `test('validates truthy', async () => { const {isAndroid } = await import('../../helpers/platform'); expect(isAndroid).toBe(true); });` to work. Can you confirm this? You also need to remove `import { isAndroid } ...` static import.

Comment: need to import all of react-native if you mock 'react-native' or you can: do https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks